# How can I make an AutoHotkey message box dissapear without clicking okay?

Tags: autohotkey

I need something like a `msgbox` displaying in my script but without the need for waiting to click okay.

What I need is to display a string for a certain duration of time and then make it disappear. It would be helpful if it can display a live timer string but not mandatory.

Something like:

```cpp
;//...
msgbox, MyInformationString; display information
sleep, 30000 ; wait 30 seconds
;// close msgbox but HOW ???
;//...
```

It doesn't have to be the `msgbox` command. but I can not figure out how to create a new popup or any other way to display information. Format is the least of my concern here.

Comment: Did you consider `tooltip` ?

Comment: If you want to create a popup anywhere on the screen, have a look at [SplashTextOn](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SplashTextOn.htm).

Comment: [SplashTextOn](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SplashTextOn.htm) is nice and I also still use it. But note, that it is marked as deprecated for some reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at `msgbox` in the [docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm). Since you are producing the `msgbox` via AutoHotkey, you can set a time limit on it that will close the message automatically.  That means that you don't have to push anything - the box appears and then just goes away.

```
MsgBox [, Options, Title, Text, Timeout]
```

`Timeout` is the last parameter:

> (optional) Timeout in seconds, which can contain a decimal point but
>   is not an expression by default.  In v1.1.06+, this can be a forced
>   expression such as % mins*60.
>
> If this value exceeds 2147483 (24.8 days), it will be set to 2147483. 
>   After the timeout has elapsed the message box will be automatically
>   closed and the IfMsgBox command will see the value TIMEOUT.
>
> Known limitation: If the MsgBox contains only an OK button, IfMsgBox
>   will think that the OK button was pressed if the MsgBox times out
>   while its own thread is interrupted by another.

Comment: Thanks. This method worked quite good for my purpose. Now I am in need of a live countdown timer display in (preferably) the same messagebox or in some other pop-up of sorts.

Comment: You should post a new question, then.  I'll look for it.

Answer (score 10):

If you would really like your own count down, you can create a GUI that acts as your MsgBox.

[image]

In this example, we have 4 parameters.

1. The Title of the Window
2. The Message
3. The Number of Seconds
4. The name of a label to call when it disappears.

Here's the way your code changes from normal MsgBox, to this one.

```
MsgBox, Title, Msg
OtherCode
return
```

to

```
MsgBoxTimed("Title", "Msg", 10, "Foo")
return
Foo:
OtherCode
return
```

This function needs to be in the same file, or [`#Include`d](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/_Include.htm)

```
MsgBoxTimed(title, msg, seconds, complete="") {
    static init = false, _seconds, _complete
    global Msg92, Seconds92
    if (!init)
    {
        init := true
        Gui, 92:Font, s24
        Gui, 92:Add, Text, vMsg92 Center w360, %msg%
        Gui, 92:Font, s30 cRed
        Gui, 92:Add, Text, vSeconds92 Center w360, %seconds%
    }

    _seconds := seconds
    _complete := complete

    GuiControl, 92:, Msg92, %msg%
    Gui, 92:Show, w400 h150, %title%

    Update92:
    GuiControl, 92:, Seconds92, %_seconds%
    _seconds -= 1
    if (_seconds > 0) {
        SetTimer, Update92, -1000
    }
    else {
        Gui, 92:Hide
        if (_complete)
            SetTimer, %_complete%, -1
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: What is it with the `92`? +1 for this nice and detailed answer!